# Using AFNetworking to fetch data from multiple resources and return

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to write an function in ObjectC which returns a Class with 3 properties. For each property the program has to fetch from a remote server (AFNetworking now), I am wondering what would a nice solution for this problem?
Here is the current structure of the the function I am writing

```
- (MyClass *)fillInClassAndReturn {
    MyClass *myClass = [MyClass new];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"Url1"
      parameters:parameter1
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             myClass.property1 = responseObject;
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             myClass.property1 = nil;
         }];
    [manager GET:@"Url2"
      parameters:parameter2
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             myClass.property2 = responseObject;
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             myClass.property2 = nil;
         }];
    [manager GET:@"Url13"
      parameters:parameter3
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             myClass.property3 = responseObject;
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             myClass.property3 = nil;
         }];
    return myClass;
}
```

This function will return `myClass` immediately after this function is called, all three properties will be `nil` at this time and when corresponding data is fetched from server, it will be filled in. So people who use this function will have to define a KVO for the returned value of the function and get notified when there is a value change.
But here is a problems with this design, It wont work if the returned value is a `NSArray/NSMutableArray` instead of `MyClass`
So is there better design so I can take care of this situation? If this design is not that horrible, how to handle the `NSArray*` case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Because this is a method that runs asynchronously, you do not want to attempt to return anything immediately, but rather employ a completion block pattern, a `completionHandler` that will be called when the three requests are done.
2. Since you have three requests that run concurrently, you need some way of knowing when all three are done. Since you're using a `NSOperation`-based solution (`AFHTTPRequestOperation`), you can use operation dependencies.

Anyway, that yields something like:

```
- (void)fillInClassWithCompletion:(void (^)(MyClass *myClass))completionHandler {
    MyClass *myClass = [MyClass new];

    NSBlockOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(myClass);
        }
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSOperation *operation1 = [manager GET:@"Url1" parameters:parameter1 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        myClass.property1 = responseObject;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        myClass.property1 = nil;
    }];
    [completionOperation addDependency:operation1];

    NSOperation *operation2 = [manager GET:@"Url2" parameters:parameter2 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        myClass.property2 = responseObject;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        myClass.property2 = nil;
    }];
    [completionOperation addDependency:operation2];

    NSOperation *operation3 = [manager GET:@"Url13" parameters:parameter3 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        myClass.property3 = responseObject;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        myClass.property3 = nil;
    }];
    [completionOperation addDependency:operation3];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:completionOperation];
}
```

That's probably the most logical approach. Technically, if you changed the `completionQueue` of the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` to be a concurrent queue, the above introduces possible race conditions, so you could alternatively use dispatch group mechanism to know if all three were done:

```
- (void)fillInClassWithCompletion:(void (^)(MyClass *myClass))completionHandler {
    MyClass *myClass = [MyClass new];

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [manager GET:@"Url1" parameters:parameter1 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        myClass.property1 = responseObject;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        myClass.property1 = nil;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [manager GET:@"Url2" parameters:parameter2 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        myClass.property2 = responseObject;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        myClass.property2 = nil;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [manager GET:@"Url13" parameters:parameter3 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        myClass.property3 = responseObject;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        myClass.property3 = nil;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];

    dispatch_group_notify(group, manager.completionQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(myClass);
        }
    });
}
```

Either way, the way you'd use this would be:

```
[object fillInClassWithCompletion:^(MyClass *myClass) {
    // use myClass here
}];
```

You might want to expand this `completionHandler` to pass back an error object, too, as that's common practice and can be useful if the caller wants to customize its error handling on the basis of the nature of the error, but I'll leave that to you.